# how to deal with RadioButton Onclick Listener

Tags: java, android, listview

i am using radiobutton and i want to change the value of variable according to radio button selected. till now i tried this code.

```
                   public int i = 1;

> > @Override       public void onClick(View v) {
>    
>                   // get selected radio button from radioGroup
>               int selectedId = radioSexGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
>    
>               // find the radiobutton by returned id
>                   radioSexButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId);
>                   
>                   if(radioMAle.isSelected() == true)
>                   {
>                       i=i+0;
>                       Log.e("MALE RADIO", "RADIO BUTTON MALE");
>                    
>                   }
>                   
>                   else if(radioFeMAle.isSelected() == true)
>                   {
>                         i=i+1;
>                   }
>    
>                   Log.e("RAdio button ID", Integer.toString(i));
>                                   
>               }
>           });
>         }
```

i want when user select male radio button value of i = 1 and when he select female i = 2.
let me know how to do this thanks

Comment: Looks like what you do should work as it is. Is there something wrong?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/radiobutton.html

refer above link

```
public void onRadioButtonClicked(View view) {
    // Is the button now checked?
    boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();

    // Check which radio button was clicked
    switch(view.getId()) {
        case R.id.radio_pirates:
            if (checked)

i=1;
            break;
        case R.id.radio_ninjas:
            if (checked)

i=2;
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: hi let me know how to call onRadioButtonClicked  @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_radio);

  radioSexGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioSex);
  radioMAle = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radioMale);
  radioFeMAle = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radioFemale);
  
 // addListenerOnButton();
 }
 
 public void onRadioButtonClicked(View view) {

Comment: <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_female"
       ...
        android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>

set this for both radio button. u also use selected changed listner instead.

Comment: thanks for aweshom answer

Answer (score 1):

You usually set a listener on the `RadioGroup` that tells you when the selected button changed. Then use the `checkedId` (`android:id` within the layout) to determine what to do.

```
radioSexGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
        switch (checkedId) {
            case R.id.button1:
                i = 0;
                break;
            case R.id.button2:
                i = 1;
                break;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: +1 Perfect...!!! Just to add a little that, in the layout xml file, all the radio buttons should be unchecked, so that user needs to click on any radio button and `onCheckChanged()` will be called.